# Check if computeIfAbsent of ConcurrentHashMap changed something

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent

How do you know that the function computeIfAbsent of a ConcurrentHashMap had to call the given generator method ("mappingFunction")?
From the Javadoc I believe it returns the new value, if one was generated and the old value if one existed. I could set an external flag from a lambda generator function but that would be awkward...

Comment: 2 upvotes, 2 downvotes, 1 fav and one answer with 4 upvotes: Quite a controversial question! Yet I didn't receive a single comment. Stay classy, Stackoverflow.

Comment: If there are downvotes here, I have to say that are totally given fore free. Good question indeed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `compute` instead:

```
map.compute(key, (k, v) -> v == null ? /*absent*/ this::getValue : /*present*/ v);
```

and add some logic to check which branch is called.

Answer (score 0):

I think using `compute` is the right way, but checking whether the `mappingFunction` was called  within the compute's `remappingFunction` may not what be you want. I needed that information outside of the lambda, after `compute` had finished. I used the old array trick to extract the information out of the lambda.

```
final var isAbsent = new boolean[1];
instances.compute(keys, (k, value) -> {
    isAbsent[0] = (value == null);
    return Objects.requireNonNullElseGet(value, mappingFunction);
});
if (isAbsent[0]) {
    // entry was absent
}
```

By the way, if the map contains `null` values, then the lambda's `value` parameter can be `null` even though an entry was present. Calling `requireNonNullElseGet` ensures that no `null` values are put into the map here.